# Android alarm manager pending intent when app is closed

Tags: java, android

I'm using alarm manager to setup pending intent, so my code gets executed even if app is closed

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pendingIntent);
```

The problem is that it also works when app is open, i need to configure it to work only if app is closed. Is there a way to configure it through alarm manager or from the activity?

Comment: which BroadcastReceiver are u using the manifest one or the manual code one?

Comment: Alarm Manager doesn't work when app is closed. You need to use STICKY SERVICE for this which will run in background...

Comment: create background service for this and check if youractivity is in front than dont execute your code..

Comment: @NaveedAli that's how i do currently, my background task gets fired on each interval, and i check if app is running or not, but i thought there would be way to avoid running background activity if app is open

Answer (score 1):

Alarms operate outside the scope of your application, so you need to manually cancel them if you no longer need them. You can use the [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) method of `AlarmManager` to accomplish this.
Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to understand if your application is closing. On way could be using [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/13809991#13809991) for more informations. As you can read there

> Just check if the number of stopped activities is equal to the number
>   of started activities. If they're equal, your application is being
>   backgrounded

At this point you can set the alarm.
Conversely

> If there are more started activities, your application is still
>   visible. If there are more resumed than paused activities, your
>   application is not only visible, but it's also in the foreground

when in this situation, you can use the `cancel()` method of the `AlarmManager`.
Bear in mind that all alarms are cancelled whenever the device is rebooted.

Comment: well said mavi. Actually when machine rebooted, the Background Service aligned with apps get stopped until it starts again.

@Edgar: "to avoid running background activity if app is open"- check the application is_running on the service and then dont do the task if it is running.